# Plotly: Change Mouseover label

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly

I am using plotly js to draw a wind rose chart following is a image, but when I mouseover on a section of chart it shows only Direction and Percentage.

How can I add wind speed like this section is for 2-5 m/s wind speed.

[image]